# SVG Icons only blurry on Horizontal Centered Div

Tags: firefox, svg, blurry

for my wordpress theme i use svg icons whichs works pretty well expect some problems with firefox. My Icons (16px by 16px) getting blurry if they are in a container that gets centered horizontally. (chrome is fine)

This is how they look in centered mode: (blurry, just look at the + )
http://cl.ly/image/0X2x361K3U0u

This is how they look if they are not centered:
http://cl.ly/image/2g2d2n1m3M0k

My Container is centered via margin: 0 auto and got a width of 1170px.

I personally assume that this is a bit like the good ol Flash problems where you center something and then the picture maybe sits on some half pixel values like 145.5 and gets blurry. Do you guys know any workaround for this?

ps: These are all inline SVG, here is an example ( the + ):

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" enable-background="new 0 0 16 16" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon points="1,7 7,7 7,1 9,1 9,7 15,7 15,9 9,9 9,15 7,15 7,9 1,9 "/>
</svg>
```

Thanks a lot in advance. :)
Michael

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in Firefox 24 by the patch in [bug 600207](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600207). You can download a [Nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) or Aurora to see the difference.